# converting to boxing syntax requires casting UIBarMetrics Warning

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, uibarmetrics

```
[self backgroundImages][[NSNumber numberWithInt:barMetrics]] = backgroundImage;
```

How can I solve this warning?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get rid of the warning use

```
[NSNumber numberWithInteger:metrics]
```

or

```
[NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)metrics]
```

because metrics is an NSInteger and numberWithInt accepts int not NSInteger.

But what you really want is

```
[self backgroundImages][(int)metrics];
```

Comment: Technically, you'll also want to cast the item in the array as a `UIImage`, since objects in `NSArray` are `id`: `UIImage *image = (UIImage *)[self background][NSNumber numberWithInteger:metrics]`

Comment: @richarddas A cast there would serve no purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You try to pass NSNumber as a index to your array but you should pass int instead:

```
[self backgroundImages][It should be an int number]
```

I assume backgroundImages is array.
BarMetrics is an UIBarMetrics type you cannot pass it as an int.

You can do something like that:

```
int i = -1;
if (barMetrics == UIBarMetricsDefault)
    i = 0;
if (barMetrics == UIBarMetricsLandscapePhone)
    i = 1;
// and so on....
[self backgroundImages][i]
```